# Comic style scheme

Tags: inkscape, svg, css, html, comics

I would like to build a scheme in comic style.

I found the CSS markup that I like (https://codepen.io/mp/pen/ldAFs)

[image]

It seems like the following tags do the job

```
border-width: 3px 4px 3px 5px;
border-radius:95% 4% 92% 5%/4% 95% 6% 95%;
transform: rotate(2deg);
```

Then I tried to draw the blocks in SVG format by using InkScape with changing style settings via XML editor. However, when I add one of the attributes (transform) and press Set, it disappears, it seems like SVG doesn't support all CSS attributes.

My question is what's the easiest way to build such a scheme?

Comment: Try to rotate a rectangle and see what that gives in the XML editor.

Comment: You can't expect SVG to work just like HTML + CSS does, it's a different technology. SVGs don't have borders like the other does. It would be best to recreate these in a vector editor like Inkscape.

Comment: Some years later :) You could build your scheme in HTML/CSS like above and then print it to pdf. The PDF should be editable in Inkscape then. Didn't even know these shapes are possible in CSS

Comment: @AAGD PDFs already are editable in Inkscape.